# How do I get 64 bit %ProgramFiles% in batch file that is run from 32 bit application?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, batch

Problem is that in my case, a batch file run from 32 bit application have %ProgramFiles% expanding to "C:\Program Files (x86)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get it from environment variable `%ProgramW6432%`. This variable exists on 64-bit Windows versions and always points to 64-bit instance of `Program Files`.

Answer (score -1):

In a batch file is spawned by a 32bit exectutable, I found that all ProgramFiles related environment variables contain the "Program Files (x86)" location.  As a kludge, you can assume the 64bit folder is on the same drive, but lacks the " (x86)" substring at the end.  The value with the substring stripped may be computed in batch as follows:

```
   set Programs=%ProgramFiles(x86)%
   set Programs64=%Programs:~0,-6%
```

Comment: Determining the environment, before setting an internal variable, is the proper solution. Just blindly stripping 6 characters does not seem like a very good idea.

Answer (score -2):

Read this SO for your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071300/how-to-create-a-batch-file-which-work-for-both-program-files-and-program-filesx

It uses environment variables to identify x86 and 64-Bit Program Files folders

Comment: I don't see anything related to my question on that link. Please point the answer out, it there is any

Comment: @user331681 - **The accepted answer is the answer to this question.**